# how can this socket.io javascript example be translated to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io, typescript-typings

I'm testing the socket.io package and playing with the 'chat-example' (https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and it works fine in javascript.

However, i would like to translate that example to TypeScript. 15 lines of code. Should be easy right? But no, I'm stuck with that.

if the file extension is .js, vscode's intellisense recognizes the 'require'd types, but as soon as I change the extension to .ts, the types are no longer recognized. I've tried to convert the 'require' statements to 'import' statements, but this also does not seem to work.
What would be the proper typescript equivalent of the code below

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried import like below?

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import io from 'socket.io';
```

Importe like this will not work

```
import { express } from 'express';
import { http } from 'http';
import { io } from 'socket.io';
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. I was not familiar with that import syntax